# Reuse value in snippet

Tags: snippets

I recently switched to using `neovim` + `deoplete` + `neosnippets` and I'm trying to get a snippet to do a thing that I'm *pretty* sure that I've been able to do in `UltiSnips`. In a template I'd like to be able to enter a value for `${0:THING}` and have it be reused throughout the snippet output without retyping it. I'm not sure if there's a point in providing the snippet because it doesn't do what I want, but just in case my description isn't clear enough, this:

```
snippet thing
abbr    thing
    #ifndef THING_${0:TYPE}_H
    #define THING_${0}_H

    #include <something.h>

    BEGIN_DECLS

    // ...

    END_DECLS

    #endif /* THING_${0}_H */
```

would produce:

```
#ifndef THING_TEST_H
#define THING_TEST_H

#include <something.h>

BEGIN_DECLS

// ...

END_DECLS

#endif /* THING_TEST_H */
```

if I hit `<C-k>` and enter 'TEST' when prompted.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is synchronized placeholders; I just couldn't find anything online/in the manual because I didn't know the terminology. The correct snippet would be:

```
snippet thing
abbr    thing
    #ifndef THING_${1:something}_H
    #define THING_$1_H

    #include <something.h>

    BEGIN_DECLS

    // ...

    END_DECLS

    #endif /* THING_$1_H */
```

For some reason, starting from `0` creates an error.